# python : Why this code did not work? (invalid syntax)

Tags: python, numpy

[image]

hi im studying python and i dont know why this code did not work.

can you help me ? thanks

Comment: You have left out necessary parentheses in lines 6 and 7: `print np.cross(A,B)` should be `print (np.cross(A,B))`. Are you maybe working from study material for Python 2? If so, please abandon it.

Comment: Where's the error?  Show the prints that do work.  Don't just show code and ask for generic help!

Comment: no, it doesn't work

Comment: If adding parentheses  didn't work please add the new code and error

Comment: oh, it works and other things apper wrong

Comment: list multipication with list is not operation

Comment: you need to convert it into ndarray or other data structure

Comment: okay maybe this is point of this questions. thanks guyssssssssssss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three errors. First, `print` is a function in Python 3, not a statement, so you need to use parentheses. The second is that with `A*B` you are trying to multiply regular Python lists, but you cannot do that. Also, `A+B` works, but it concatenates the lists instead of adding their elements, which is probably not what you wanted. You should use the definitions

```
A = np.array([2, 1, -1])
B = np.array([1, -1, 2])
```

The third is that you are trying to multiply matrices of incompatible dimensions in the third section.

By the way, the `np.matrix` class is deprecated, so you should not use it.

Comment: thanks for perfect answer. it helps a lot. again, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
A=[2,1,-1]
B=[1,-1,2]
print(A+B)
print(np.cross(A,B)) #AXB
print(np.dot(A,B)) 
A=np.array([2,1,-1])
B=np.array([1,-1,2])
print(A+B)
print (np.cross(A,B)) #AXB
print (np.dot(A,B)) # AB
print (A*B)
A=np.matrix([2,1,-1])
B=np.matrix([1,-1,2])
print(A+B)
print (np.cross(A,B))
```

[image]